# accordion menu using jscrollpane jquery plugin - keeps bouncing back to top on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I've created a menu with javascript. The user needs to click on the hamburger menu icon to open it. Once open, there's an accordion menu with various options. I'm using the jscrollpane jquery plugin for the scrollbar styling, because I want to be able to control the style in MS Edge.

The problem I'm having is that when I click on an accordion item with many list items (Class A or Class B in my menu), as you scroll down the menu always bounces back up to the top. It doesn't just rest at the bottom of the list of items. I believe this is being introduced by the jscrollpane plugin, but I'm not sure. I've spent hours making changes, and just can't fix it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is a plunker with all of the code, where you can see how it's functioning:
https://plnkr.co/edit/uPh87hA7r3HlsL2DYBAO

Here's the main index file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css">
        <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
        <link media="all" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>
    <body>

    <nav id="menu"></nav>
    <div id="datas">
      <div id="nav" class="open-close">
        <div id="navtitle">MENU</div>

        <a href="#" class="opener add"><span>menu</span></a>
        <ul class="slide">
              <li id="itemdialog" class="nolink">Select item</li>
              <div id="accordion">
                <h3>Class A</h3>
                <div>
                  <div class="item aush"><div class="itemname">Aush</div><div class="scientificname">Puffinus lherminieri</div></div>
                  <div class="item blra"><div class="itemname">Blra</div><div class="scientificname">Laterallus jamaicensis</div></div>
                  <div class="item blsk"><div class="itemname">Blsk</div><div class="scientificname">Rynchops niger</div></div>
                  <div class="item bwha"><div class="itemname">Bwha</div><div class="scientificname">Buteo platypterus</div></div>
                  <div class="item cw"><div class="itemname">Cw</div><div class="scientificname">Setophaga cerulea</div></div>
                  <div class="item osp"><div class="itemname">Osp</div><div class="scientificname">Pandion haliaetus</div></div>
                  <div class="item redh"><div class="itemname">Redh</div><div class="scientificname">Aythya americana</div></div>
                  <div class="item whcr"><div class="itemname">Whcr</div><div class="scientificname">Grus americana</div></div>
                  <div class="item wt"><div class="itemname">Wt</div><div class="scientificname">Hylocichla mustelina</div></div>
                </div>
                <h3>Class B</h3>
                <div>
                  <div class="item tarpon"><div class="itemname">Tarpon</div><div class="scientificname">Megalops atlanticus</div></div>
                  <div class="item bm"><div class="itemname">Blm</div><div class="scientificname">Makaira nigricans</div></div>
                  <div class="item bft"><div class="itemname">Bft</div><div class="scientificname">Thunnus thynnus</div></div>
                  <div class="item bus"><div class="itemname">Bus</div><div class="scientificname">Carcharhinus leucas</div></div>
                  <div class="item df"><div class="itemname">Df</div><div class="scientificname">Coryphaena hippurus</div></div>
                  <div class="item gagg"><div class="itemname">Gagg</div><div class="scientificname">Mycteroperca microlepis</div></div>
                  <div class="item gulfm"><div class="itemname">Gulfm</div><div class="scientificname">Brevoortia patronus</div></div>
                  <div class="item gulfs"><div class="itemname">Gulfsn</div><div class="scientificname">Acipenser oxyrinchus</div></div>
                  <div class="item mutts"><div class="itemname">Mutts</div><div class="scientificname">Lutjanus analis</div></div>
                  <div class="item sb"><div class="itemname">Sb</div><div class="scientificname">Morone saxatilis</div></div>
                  <div class="item ws"><div class="itemname">Ws</div><div class="scientificname">Rhincodon typus</div></div>
                </div>
                <h3>Class C</h3>
                <div>
                  <div class="item sw"><div class="itemname">Sw</div><div class="scientificname">Physeter macrocephalus</div></div>
                  <div class="item man"><div class="itemname">Man</div><div class="scientificname">Trichechus manatus</div></div>
                </div>
                <h3>Class D</h3>
                <div>
                  <div class="item gst"><div class="itemname">Gst</div><div class="scientificname">Chelonia mydas</div></div>
                  <div class="item kemps"><div class="itemname">Kemps</div><div class="scientificname">Lepidochelys kempii</div></div>
                  <div class="item lbst"><div class="itemname">Lbst</div><div class="scientificname">Dermochelys coriacea</div></div>
                  <div class="item lst"><div class="itemname">Lst</div><div class="scientificname">Caretta caretta</div></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <li id="aboutdialog">A Link</li>
              <li id="clearall">Another Link</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#nav > ul.slide').jScrollPane();
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's the menu.js file:

```
            // main menu
            jQuery(function(){
                $('nav ul').addClass('slide js-slide-hidden');
                $('li.dropdown a').attr('data-toggle', 'none');
                initOpenClose();
            });

            // open-close init
            function initOpenClose() {
                jQuery('.open-close').openClose({
                    activeClass: 'active',
                    opener: '.opener',
                    slider: '.slide',
                    animSpeed: 400,
                    effect: 'slide'
                });
            }
            /*
             * jQuery Open/Close plugin
             */
            ;(function($) {
                function OpenClose(options) {
                    this.options = $.extend({
                        addClassBeforeAnimation: true,
                        hideOnClickOutside: true,
                        activeClass:'active',
                        opener:'.opener',
                        slider:'.slide',
                        animSpeed: 400,
                        effect:'fade',
                        event:'click'
                    }, options);
                    this.init();
                }
                OpenClose.prototype = {
                    init: function() {
                        if(this.options.holder) {
                            this.findElements();
                            this.attachEvents();
                            this.makeCallback('onInit');
                        }
                    },
                    findElements: function() {
                        this.holder = $(this.options.holder);
                        this.opener = this.holder.find(this.options.opener);
                        this.slider = this.holder.find(this.options.slider);
                    },
                    attachEvents: function() {
                        // add handler
                        var self = this;
                        this.eventHandler = function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            if (self.slider.hasClass(slideHiddenClass)) {
                                self.showSlide();
                            } else {
                                self.hideSlide();
                            }
                        };
                        self.opener.bind(self.options.event, this.eventHandler);

                        // hover mode handler
                        if(self.options.event === 'over') {
                            self.opener.bind('mouseenter', function() {
                                self.showSlide();
                            });
                            self.holder.bind('mouseleave', function() {
                                self.hideSlide();
                            });
                        }

                        // outside click handler
                        self.outsideClickHandler = function(e) {
                            if(self.options.hideOnClickOutside) {
                                var target = $(e.target);
                                if (!target.is(self.holder) && !target.closest(self.holder).length) {
                                    self.hideSlide();
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        // set initial styles
                        if (this.holder.hasClass(this.options.activeClass)) {
                            $(document).bind('click touchstart', self.outsideClickHandler);
                        } else {
                            this.slider.addClass(slideHiddenClass);
                        }
                    },
                    showSlide: function() {
                        $('#pane').removeClass('hide');
                        $('#pane').addClass('show');
                        var self = this;
                        if (self.options.addClassBeforeAnimation) {
                            self.holder.addClass(self.options.activeClass);
                        }
                        self.slider.removeClass(slideHiddenClass);
                        $(document).bind('click touchstart', self.outsideClickHandler);

                        self.makeCallback('animStart', true);
                        toggleEffects[self.options.effect].show({
                            box: self.slider,
                            speed: self.options.animSpeed,
                            complete: function() {
                                if (!self.options.addClassBeforeAnimation) {
                                    self.holder.addClass(self.options.activeClass);
                                }
                                self.makeCallback('animEnd', true);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    hideSlide: function() {
                        $('#pane').removeClass('show');
                        $('#pane').addClass('hide');
                        var self = this;
                        if (self.options.addClassBeforeAnimation) {
                            self.holder.removeClass(self.options.activeClass);
                        }
                        $(document).unbind('click touchstart', self.outsideClickHandler);

                        self.makeCallback('animStart', false);
                        toggleEffects[self.options.effect].hide({
                            box: self.slider,
                            speed: self.options.animSpeed,
                            complete: function() {
                                if (!self.options.addClassBeforeAnimation) {
                                    self.holder.removeClass(self.options.activeClass);
                                }
                                self.slider.addClass(slideHiddenClass);
                                self.makeCallback('animEnd', false);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    destroy: function() {
                        this.slider.removeClass(slideHiddenClass).css({display:''});
                        this.opener.unbind(this.options.event, this.eventHandler);
                        this.holder.removeClass(this.options.activeClass).removeData('OpenClose');
                        $(document).unbind('click touchstart', this.outsideClickHandler);
                    },
                    makeCallback: function(name) {
                        if(typeof this.options[name] === 'function') {
                            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                            args.shift();
                            this.options[name].apply(this, args);
                        }
                    }
                };

                // add stylesheet for slide on DOMReady
                var slideHiddenClass = 'js-slide-hidden';
                $(function() {
                    var tabStyleSheet = $('<style type="text/css">')[0];
                    var tabStyleRule = '.' + slideHiddenClass;
                    tabStyleRule += '{position:absolute !important;left:-9999px !important;top:-9999px !important;display:block !important}';
                    if (tabStyleSheet.styleSheet) {
                        tabStyleSheet.styleSheet.cssText = tabStyleRule;
                    } else {
                        tabStyleSheet.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tabStyleRule));
                    }
                    $('head').append(tabStyleSheet);
                });

                // animation effects
                var toggleEffects = {
                    slide: {
                        show: function(o) {
                            o.box.stop(true).hide().slideDown(o.speed, o.complete);
                        },
                        hide: function(o) {
                            o.box.stop(true).slideUp(o.speed, o.complete);
                        }
                    },
                    fade: {
                        show: function(o) {
                            o.box.stop(true).hide().fadeIn(o.speed, o.complete);
                        },
                        hide: function(o) {
                            o.box.stop(true).fadeOut(o.speed, o.complete);
                        }
                    },
                    none: {
                        show: function(o) {
                            o.box.hide().show(0, o.complete);
                        },
                        hide: function(o) {
                            o.box.hide(0, o.complete);
                        }
                    }
                };

                // jQuery plugin interface
                $.fn.openClose = function(opt) {
                    return this.each(function() {
                        jQuery(this).data('OpenClose', new OpenClose($.extend(opt, {holder: this})));
                    });
                };


            //ACCORDION

                $( function() {

                        // allow more than one group to be open at once
                    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                      collapsible: true,
                            active: 'none'
                    });


            // JSCROLLPANE

                        //init menu height
                        $('#nav > ul.slide').css('height', '270px');

                        var width  = window.innerWidth,
                            height = window.innerHeight;
                        var calc = height - 140 + "px";

                                if (height >= 740){
                                    $('h3#ui-id-1, h3#ui-id-3, h3#ui-id-5, h3#ui-id-7').click( function(){
                                        if($(this).hasClass('ui-accordion-header-active')){
                                        }else{
                                            $('#nav > ul.slide, .jspContainer, .jspTrack, .jspDrag').css('height', '270px');
                                        }
                                    });

                                }else{
                                    $('h3#ui-id-1, h3#ui-id-3, h3#ui-id-5, h3#ui-id-7').click( function(){
                                        if($(this).hasClass('ui-accordion-header-active')){
                                            $('#nav > ul.slide, .jspContainer, .jspTrack, .jspDrag').css('height', calc);
                                            $('.jspContainer, .jspTrack, .jspDrag').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
                                        }else{
                                            $('#nav > ul.slide, .jspContainer, .jspTrack, .jspDrag').css('height', '270px');
                                        }
                                    });
                                };
                 });

            }(jQuery));
```

This is the jscrollpane plugin: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/